# Error "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" cant figure out how to fix it

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent

I have some string that i write into the Edittext on my first activity and im trying to send it to the Edittext on the other activity by pressing Button, but it gives me an Error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kp_orginizer/com.example.kp_orginizer.calendar}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0"

Could somebody please help me

Here is my onCLick method on the first Activity:

```
    public void calendarOR(View v, AdapterView<?> parent, int position, long id) {
        String data = cala.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, calendar.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

My second method:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    userId = extras.getString("id");
}
if (userId !=null) {
    userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + dbelper.TABLE + " where " + dbelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{userId});
    userCursor.moveToFirst();
    date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
    userCursor.close();
}
```

It is complaining about "date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));" string

Here is an Error code:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kp_orginizer, PID: 7787
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kp_orginizer/com.example.kp_orginizer.calendar}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:515)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:52)
    at com.example.kp_orginizer.calendar.onCreate(calendar.java:94)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is how i fill my database:

```
    public void save(View view) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        int idishnik = 1;
        cv.put(dbelper.COLUMN_NOTE, note.getText().toString());
        cv.put(dbelper.COLUMN_DATE, cala.getText().toString());
        cv.put(dbelper.ID_TABLITSY, idishnik);

        if (userId > 0) {
            db.update(dbelper.TABLE, cv, dbelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + userId, null);
        } else {
            db.insert(dbelper.TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        goHome();
    }
```

Comment: i added now my method to fill database if i got you right

Comment: Have you tried printing the userId when you set it in the database and again when you access it to make sure they match?

Comment: Im not sure how to do this but will try, i just have the same method in my project and it's work exactly how i want to, the only diffeence between this not working methods and those which work is that here i use button and there i just click on listview item and everything work and match

Comment: Try `System.out.println("DEBUG: adding/accessing userId = " + userId);` then search for "DEBUG:" in the logcat

Comment: i tried it and now i see that for some reason instead of userId i actually get the string that im trying to set in my second activity edittext

Comment: and actually when imy longId is long, not string, it says that it's equals 0 i think its because i announce it like "long userId = 0" just as i do it in my working part of code

Comment: The userId you send is whatever is in the `cala` EditText. If that's not what you intend to send you'll need to fix that logic.

Comment: Omg it worked! i just had to do "date.setText(usedId);" instead of "date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));" now i just hope it wont break anything else
Thank you so much

Comment: I tried to do this as i did it with "onItemClick" where i could send an item id to the other Activity as "long" and with the button i cant do such thing i guess

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, hopefully learned some debugging techniques in the process! I'll add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear what you are passing as `userId` is not a valid/present database key. If you just want to show what you passed in the EditText instead of using it to get something from the database you would just do

```
if (userId != null) {
    date.setText(userId);
}
```